# Triggering 'onload' behavior in AJAX return data

Tags: jquery, ajax, load, triggers

A friend and I are looking over a website involving a button that makes an AJAX call that upon successful return, loads HTML into a specified DIV tag and calls a Javascript function. The problem is that it will only work twice. After clicking it twice it fails to work properly. We are trying to dynamically control what the ready() invoked function is.

here is a simple case:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.1.js"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
  $("#trigger").click(
    function(){
     $("#target").load('load.html');
    }
  );
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="target" style='width:200px;height:200px;border: 1px solid black'>
Not Loaded
</div>
<input type="button" value="Load AJAX" id="trigger" />
</body>
</html>
```

load.html contains:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
  alert('loaded stuff');
});
</script>
loaded
```

Here is the sample: http://phoenixillusion.net/demos/ajax/

Thanks!
EDIT Forgot to put information about the contents of load.html

Comment: Which browser are you testing in, and what do you *want* the behavior to be?

Comment: Firefox running on Ubuntu 10.4

Comment: Can you try it against jQuery 1.4.2?

Comment: @Nick yes, works in 1.4.2. Looks like a bug of that particular version.

Comment: Thanks, that appears to be the problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should upgrade to jQuery 1.4.2 which included a pretty heavy re-write of the events module, [you can find full release notes here](http://blog.jquery.com/2010/02/19/jquery-142-released/).

Answer (score 0):

It actually is making the call to load each time although it does not appear to be since the popup does not come up after 2 clicks.

Use a console like chrome or firebug and watch the XHR on each click you will see it makes a call each click.

Comment: Right, so do you know why 

$("#target").load('load.html'); 

isn't being called?

Comment: It is being called, each and everytime as I said above. 
See screen shot below, each load.html on there is from a click on your page.  Which is what .load() is doing in your code. 

http://j.imagehost.org/0628/image.png

Comment: I'm sorry for the confusion, I messed up the wording. 

We knew the .load() is working properly, but are curious why the JS function in load.html isn't being called.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the javascript code in the main program instead:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
  $("#trigger").click(
    function() {
      $("#target").load('load.html', function() {
        alert('Loaded');
      });
    }
  );
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, The problem is that in our website one Javascript function makes an API call to our server via .post(), then it returns and calls other JS handler functions. Thanks though, The problem turned out to be the JQuery version, there is a bug with version 1.4.1